# Check if FusiontableControl insert query successfully uploaded before proceeding

Tags: google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

So basically, I am using **App Inventor** with fusion tables and I have a `while` loop that uploads every single row of the query and a counter that counts the number of successfully uploaded rows to Google fusion tables.

The loop is like:

```
while counter <= databaselength
(
  call insertquery
  counter=counter+1
)
```

I need to check if every row of the query was successfully uploaded inside the while loop before setting counter=counter+1

Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The `fusiontable controls` in **App Inventor** work asynchronously, which means, you should use this workflow:(pseudocode)

1. insert data (one row)
2. after inserting one row you can check in the `fusiontable controls got result` event, if the insert was successful and if there are more data to insert
   if yes, insert data (next row)
   if no: end

**In the following example** https://puravidaapps.com/filebyfile.php **you can learn how to work with asynchronous components**. The example however uses the web component. Yes, it's different, but it uses the same logic as mentioned in the pseudo code above. Now use this pseudo code together with the `fusiontable controls`.

Comment: The example you are pointing at only checks if there is internet for one time , i need the application to check for connectivity every time it tries to insert a row.